# What’s the purpose of the following code ? Increase public storage usage?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I found the following code in [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8e2a84d6ade1e7fffee039a35ef5f19f13057152#code).

```
// `hat` address is unique root user (has every role) and the
// unique owner of role 0 (typically 'sys' or 'internal')
contract DSChief is DSRoles, DSChiefApprovals {

    function setOwner(address owner_) public {
        owner_;
        revert();
    }

    function setAuthority(DSAuthority authority_) public {
        authority_;
        revert();
    }

    function setRootUser(address who, bool enabled) public {
        who; enabled;
        revert();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or the only purpose of lefting this in non testing contract is to increase transaction fees ?

Comment: Why not simply remove this dead code since those functions are already overloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody wanted to implement a contract which inherits from `DSRoles` and `DSChiefApprovals`, yet make sure that these 3 specific functions are not called from an instance of that contract, by overriding them and immediately revert.

You should probably look into `DSRoles` and `DSChiefApprovals`, and try to understand why these specific functions are not to be called from `DSChief`.

BTW, assuming that `revert` invokes `require(false)`, all transactions are reverted and no extra fee is applied, so there is most definitely no intention here to "increase transaction fees".

Comment: This is the main DAI contract. A token with a volume more than 1 million per days. Not the kind of developers which leave dead code around. **Why not simply remove this dead code since those functions are already overloaded elsewhere in the code ?**

Comment: @user2284570: If those functions are `public` in those two base contracts, then the derived contract must "block" them. Whoever implemented this contract probably wanted to avoid these functions being called from it for some reason. They probably preferred to keep the base contracts untouched, possibly because they are taken from a different repository, so they preferred not to touch a "service" provided by some third party. I'm just speculating here of course, but when you're using someone else's code (presumably those two base contracts), then there's typically a good reason not to touch it.